# How to enable a program in oracle job schedular?

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

Here is my code. When I am executing  execute

```
dbms_scheduler.run_job('daily_update_job_v1');
```

getting the following error

> ORA-27367: program ".PROG_RESET_LOG_STATUS_V1" associated with this
>   job is disabled .

Any help on the following issue . Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reset_log_status_v1 ( LOG_STATUS  IN   
VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
 UPDATE (
      SELECT
            B.LOG_STATUS 

    FROM    LP_QUAT_ISSUE_MST A,
            LP_QUAT_ISSUE_DTL B
    WHERE   A.QUAT_NO = B.QUAT_NO 
    AND     (trunc(A.QUAT_DT) + A.NO_DAY_GIVEN) <= trunc(SYSDATE)
)   
SET LOG_STATUS ='N';
END;

BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
program_name      => 'PROG_RESET_LOG_STATUS_V1',
program_action     => 'RESET_LOG_STATUS_V1',
program_type      => 'STORED_PROCEDURE');
END;


BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
 schedule_name   => 'daily_update_v1',
 start_date    => SYSTIMESTAMP,
 repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=DAILY; INTERVAL=1',
 end_date     => SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '365' day,
 comments     => 'DAILY UPDATE');
END;


BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
  job_name     => 'daily_update_job_v1',
  program_name   => 'PROG_RESET_LOG_STATUS_V1',
  schedule_name   => 'daily_update_v1'
  );
END;

execute dbms_scheduler.run_job('daily_update_job_v1');
```

Comment: With [`ENABLE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#i1012587)? Or enable it [during creation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72306)?

Comment: Can you help me with the syntex ? Thanks

Comment: The syntax is documented in the PL/SQL Packages and Types manual.  There, in reference to the `enabled` option of `CREATE JOB` it specifically says *By default, this attribute is set to FALSE and, therefore, the job is created as disabled. *  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('PROG_RESET_LOG_STATUS_V1');
```